# What happens when the Close Queue is empty...?

Tags: discussion

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue is one of the more exciting things I've read lately -- and not just because of the animated Fred gif... I feel the same excitement I did in 1996 when I used a transparent gif to position a marquee tag so I could highlight the "Sign my Guestbook" link on Geocities.

**So my question is, what will happen once the queue hits ZERO?**

Do we return to the slog of reviewing close votes once it starts up again?  Or take a moment of victory!

I feel like streamers should shoot out of my monitor... but since that is *totally ridiculous*, I recommend the following reasonable options should be considered for everyone who helped burn down the queue during the recent time period:

1. Offer the reviewers a free Stack Overflow membership for a year
2. The person who closes the final post should get a "Ultimate Burninator" gold badge
3. Free unicorn rides at the Stack Overflow offices (in case of shortage, rhinos may be used as fat gray stand-ins)
4. Hand-knitted reproductions of the reviews per day chart

[image: reviews per day]

**Are there better options?**

Comment: I thought my stack overflow membership was already free

Comment: @RichardTingle who have I been paying for the last year??

Comment: \*isn't sure if joking\* unless you mean stack overflow careers

Comment: @RichardTingle no it was meant as a joke. So were the unicorns. Unless you have some stashed beside your rhinos :)

Comment: ........no unicorns! You monster!

Comment: @RichardTingle the only serious part of that was #4. You knit, right?

Comment: Are we talking about when the queue *actually* hits 0, or when the fuzzied version hits 0? If it's the latter, then it was already mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223349/189840)

Comment: When the [current votes threshold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut) puts the queue in a low size (over a period of time - possibly a few days), we will lower it. What will happen when the threshold is back to "normal" and the queue hits 0? Let that happen first, then we decide ;)